# How to layout a custom listviewitem with variable textview and two buttons on one line

Tags: android, listview, button, textview, android-relativelayout

I've created a custom listview. All works fine though I struggle with the layout of the listitem.

The idea is to have a textview which can have a variable length (multilines is possible) and two buttons next to the textview all on one line.

This is what I have:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_weight=".80" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="A"
        android:layout_weight=".10"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="B"
        android:layout_weight=".10"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button1" />
```

This works fine though my problem is that the textview fills out the parent and pushes the buttons of the screen. (when I have a short text the buttons are vissible)

So basically, what I need is a 80% wide textview aligned to the left and two 10% wide buttons aligned to the right. Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Try changing the `width` of all to "0dp" and add `android:singleLine="false" ` to your `TextView`

Comment: And change `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout` as others have suggested. Didn't notice you were using that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `layout_weight` with `RelativeLayout`.  Try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="A" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="B" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Perfect, this works. Thanks! Maybe one last question, the listitem height is not properly addapted based on the height of the textview. I can fix this by adding some bottom margin to the textview but that's probably not the way to go.

Comment: The list item height will be whatever the height of this LinearLayout is.  What exactly do you want the height to be?  Maybe add some padding to the LinearLayout?

Comment: Just so theres the correct amount of margin above and below the text so the listitem looks nice and doesn't cuts of the last line of text (for instance when the text is 4 lines heigh)

Comment: Maybe add `android:padding="5dp"` to the LinearLayout and `android:layout_gravity="center"` to all 3 child views?  Also you can center the text inside the TextView with `android:gravity="center"`.  There's lots of tweaks like this you can make, you just have to play with it.

Answer (score 0):

Change to LinearLayout. You cannot use layout_weight with RelativeLayout.

Good Luck